# How to change url instantly without waiting for model to load on slow connection?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

Is there any way to change page url instantly when clicking on a link without waiting for the model to load?

I'm using `ember-data`.

Comment: why would you need that in the first place, where model is necessary to render the the UI?

Comment: Because if the connection is slow, and if the user hits refresh, it will keep him in the same page.